# TransferHandler without layout

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying t code a JPanel as a space to draw figures on. to do this, I've set the layout to null

```
mainPanel.setLayout(null);
```

then,I've inserted some buttons inside the main Panel,to try to implement a drag and drop feature.

```
btn.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        Dimension size=btn.getPreferredSize();
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        TransferHandler handle = button.getTransferHandler();
        handle.exportAsDrag(button, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
    }
});
```

my question is, can I use theTransferHandler in a null layout? 
as soon as I start dragging things, the mouse cursor turns in a shape like this:
[forbidden action](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/2564913/blocked_cursor_disabled_forbidden_mouse_pointer_icon#size=256)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TransferHandler is for transferring data, not moving the button around the panel. So the layout has no effect.

In your case you are setting the TransferHandler for "text", which means you are trying to transfer the "text" of the button to some other component.

```
btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        Dimension size=btn.getPreferredSize();
        JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
        TransferHandler handle = button.getTransferHandler();
        handle.exportAsDrag(button, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
    }
});
```

There is no `mouseDragged` event in the MouseListener. The `mouseDragged` event is generated in a MouseMotionListener.

When I add the MouseListener to the component for DnD support I have always added the logic to the `mousePressed` event.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) for more information and examples to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've read the documentation, and recognized that it was not what I was searching for. I added the way I solved my problem as answer. Just in case

Comment: @MicheleFattoruso: Still, your *original question* was about use of transfer handler, and the answer that you're providing is an answer, but to a different question/problem. I still posit that you should accept camicker's answer as well since his answer actually addressed your original concerns.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did, but haven't fully tested it.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the previous answers, and reading the documentation posted by @camickr, I noticed that a transferHandler wasn't exactly what I was searching for. What I needed was to move a component around a single JPanel, and not make a drag and drop a copy of it to a different panel or component. what I ended up with is simply using the setLocation function of the component, with a combination of MouseEvents and mouseMotionListeners.

```
protected class DragProcessor extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    Point pressPoint;
    Point releasePoint;

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point dragPoint = e.getPoint();

        int xDiff = pressPoint.x - dragPoint.x;
        int yDiff = pressPoint.y - dragPoint.y;

        Rectangle b = button.getBounds();
        Point p = b.getLocation();
        SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, button.getParent());
        p.x -= xDiff;
        p.y -= yDiff;
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, button.getParent());

        button.setLocation(p);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        pressPoint = e.getPoint();
        button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        releasePoint = e.getPoint();

        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
         // do whatever it is when the right button is pressed
        } else {

            int xDiff = pressPoint.x - releasePoint.x;
            int yDiff = pressPoint.y - releasePoint.y;

            Rectangle b = button.getBounds();
            Point p = b.getLocation();
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, panel.getParent());
            p.x -= xDiff;
            p.y -= yDiff;

            SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, panel.getParent());
            if (p.x <= 0) {
                p.x = 1;
            }
            if (p.x > panel.getParent().getWidth() - b.width) {
                p.x = panel.getParent().getWidth() - b.width;
            }
            if (p.y <= 0) {
                p.y = 1;
            }
            if (p.y > panel.getParent().getHeight() - b.height) {
                p.y = panel.getParent().getHeight() - b.height;
            }
            button.setLocation(p);
            getParent().repaint();
        }
    }              
}

DragProcessor dragProcessor = new DragProcessor();
myButton.getMainButton().addMouseMotionListener(dragProcessor);
myButton.getMainButton().addMouseListener(dragProcessor);
```

Comment: `What I needed was to move a component around a single JPanel,` - that is what I thought you wanted, but your question wasn't clear so I explained what dnd was used for. I was expecting your to clarify your question like you just did. In which case I would have pointed you to [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) which provides basic reusable code for dragging a component around a panel, as well as a more advanced class to additional functionality. You should not need to reference any external variables like your current code does.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the documentation, and get back to you if I have problems.